# Static content in Grizzly jersey

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

I want to serve static html pages in / and /index.html

```
final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
```

BASE_URL = http://locahost:8080/api/

```
StaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new StaticHttpHandler("/static");
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/");
```

My question is where should i put the static file in

Answer (score 7):

In your case, static data should be located in `/static` folder in root of your disk.

There are a couple of options where the static resources can be located:

- you can serve static resources from your filesystem via absolute path (e.g. `/www/static/`):

  ```
  StaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new StaticHttpHandler("/www/static/");
  server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/");
  ```
- or embedded your resources into jar archive (e.g. `/www/static.jar`):

  ```
  StaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new CLStaticHttpHandler(new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new URL("file:///www/static.jar")}));
  server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/");
  ```
- or embed static resources inside your application jar:

  ```
  StaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new CLStaticHttpHandler(YourApp.class.getClassLoader());
  server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**ATTENTION**
Cannot cast from CLStaticHttpHandler to StaticHttpHandler!

```
CLStaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new CLStaticHttpHandler(YourApp.class.getClassLoader());
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/");
```